# using full text search with a sqldatasource

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

I'm having issues with using a full text search with an sqldatasource.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM table WHERE CONTAINS(2, @text)">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbOCRSearch" Name="text" 
                Type="String" DefaultValue="" PropertyName="Text" />
</SelectParameters>
```

This works great if I only put in one search term. However if I put in two terms it throws an error.

However if I put "termone termtwo" in double quotes the query works.

how can I modify my selectcommand to add the doublequotes?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Took me a few hours of looking. In the sqldatasource we need to add a OnSelecting event.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM table WHERE CONTAINS(2, @text)" 
OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbOCRSearch" Name="text" 
                Type="String" DefaultValue="" PropertyName="Text" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Then in the code behind you'll need one of these. You can then add the quotes around the text.

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{

    e.Command.Parameters["@text"].Value = "\"" + tbOCRSearch.Text + "\"";
}
```

And now everything works like it should.